# DevExpress XtraGrid not populating a specific column

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

I am having a lot of fun with a DevExpress XtraGrid at the moment... We are binding the grid to a datatable populated via a call to a stored proc, and I am adding a new column to the mix...

I've amended the stored proc to supply the new value, tested it in SSMS and it works.

I've added a new column to the grid view...

If I stick a breakpoint in code at the point that the grid's datasource is set, the value is indeed there...

However, when the grid has bound, the column is there, but it's showing empty...

If I do this :

```
Dim s As String = grvJobSearchResults.Columns("ALTOServiceOrderID").FieldName
Dim result as String = DirectCast(grvJobSearchResults.GetRow(grvJobSearchResults.GetRowHandle(0)), System.Data.DataRowView).Item(s)
```

then I am finding the result does indeed get populated with the variable...

Still though, the grid shows an empty cell.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the `FieldName` property of the column matches the datatable column name? Have you set the `DisplayFormat` property of the column to something that might result in an empty string? That's all I can think of off the top of my head. Perhaps seeing more of the code would help.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas - Yes, I have checked the FieldName property. I haven't paid much attention to DisplayFormat, because when I inspect the content of the grid cell programmatically it comes back as null. The problem seems to be in binding but I have no idea where...

Comment: I'm stumped then. Can you strip things down to a minimal example that duplicates the problem and add that to your question?

Comment: Actually, I've just nailed it - and I'm embarrassed - case sensitivity!